# JBPM 5.3 domain specific process

Tags: jbpm

I created 2 domain specific process in jbpm 5.3 eclipse tooling. Then I stored them in my own service repository and I imported these  two process into same jbpm project.

Howver, I am only seeing one process in the palette. Is it possible to show/see two processes in palette?

Answer (score 0):

for your Domain Specific Example you have to first know that JBPM 5.4 supports drools..

and for domain specific example you have to create one METAS-INF folder in your src/main/resources

and within that create two files

In drools.rulebase.conf

```
          drools.workDefinitions = MyDefinitions.conf
```

and in MyDefinitions.conf
`import org.drools.process.core.datatype.impl.type.StringDataType;
     import org.drools.process.core.datatype.impl.type.ObjectDataType;
     [
        // the Shipment work item
        [
           "name" : "Shipment",
            "parameters" : [
              "ShipmentId" : new StringDataType(),
                "To" : new StringDataType()
          ],
           "results" : [
              "Result" : new ObjectDataType()
          ],
                "displayName" : "Shipping","customEditor":org.drools.eclipse.flow.common.editor.editpart.work.SampleCustomEditor",
          "icon" : "icons/shipping.gif"
         ]
]`

now in MyDefinitions.conf is for my Example for your it would be different

also import an icon for your domain in an Icon folder
rules in your rule folder